# What is the difference between 1) sub name() {....} 2) sub name {....} 3) sub name ($j,$j) {.....}

Tags: perl

```
1) sub name() {....}  

2) sub name {....}  

3) sub name ($j,$j) {.....}
```

**These three are the different ways to declare subroutines in Perl.
Want to know the difference between them.**

Comment: [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)

Comment: Prototypes in [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes). `3)` is invalid: `perl -we 'sub name ($j,$j){}'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl has a feature called *prototypes* that change how an invocation of that subroutine is parsed at compile time. This feature is not useful to declare an argument list. Prototypes are very limited and have to be declared before the sub is invoked.

- `sub name()` declares that this sub doesn't take any arguments. Invoking that sub with arguments is a compilation error: `name(1)` aborts with `Too many arguments for main::name`. If you invoke that sub before declaring it, you'll get an optional `main::name() called too early to check prototype` warning.
- `sub name` is the regular form without any prototypes which you should always use. It is parsed equivalently to the prototype `(@)`.
- `sub name($i, $j)` is a compilation error: `Illegal character in prototype for main::name`. The only characters allowed in the prototype sub-language are:

  - `$` scalar context. In a referene spec: scalar
  - `@` list context, slurpy. In a reference spec: array
  - `%` list context, slurpy. In a reference spec: hash
  - `*` glob or things coercible to a glob
  - `&` subroutine. In initial position: bare code block
  - `_` scalar or `$_`
  - `+` collection reference. Breaks on objects.
  - `;` end of required arguments
  - `\x` reference of type `x` where x is `$%@*&`
  - `\[…]` a reference that can be of any type in the brackets.

  In Perl arguments are passed through the `@_` array, and are unpacked like `my ($i, $j) = @_` inside the subroutine. Prototypes have nothing to do with that.

  There are however syntax extensions that hijack that position to declare arguments (not prototypes). With `signatures`, declarations like `sub foo($x, $y)` are possible. Other modules like [`Function::Parameters`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Function%3a%3aParameters) and [`Kavorka`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Kavorka) introduce new keywords (`func` or `fun`) and allow additional features like types, constraints, keyword arguments, ….